# filter with dynamic dict peewee ORM

Tags: peewee

Using peewee as my ORM, is there a way to directly filter with a dict?

For example, if I have a model

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    username = CharField(unique=True)
    password = CharField()
    email = CharField()
    join_date = DateTimeField()
```

How can I filter all results with username `Bob`, with something like

```py
params = {'username':'Bob'}
User.select().where(**params)
```

**update**

I found a solution, but I'm wondering if there's a better way ...

```py
params = {'username':'Bob'}
User.select().where(*[getattr(User, k) == v for k, v in params.items()])
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, where are you getting this "dynamic dict" from? Presumably you would want to do some field validation and things before just hucking shit at the database -- and during that time you could move it into a better data-structure.

Also note that the only operation you would be able to do with the above is equality testing.

To answer your question, Peewee has a `.filter()` method which behaves like the one in Django. So you can throw your dictionary of data at it. docs are sparse because this method is really not recommended:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.filter