# peewee ORM - filter on a join using attributes from all models involved in the join

Tags: peewee

@coleifer, Thank you for giving us Peewee.

I have a join from two Models that are connected by an FK constraint. I am querying the combined result with a query like the one below:

`Model1.select(Model1, Model2).join(Model2).dicts()`

I want to apply filters on the combined query, using attributes from both Models.

I was guided towards filter from the answer in this question: [filter with dynamic dict peewee ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57630286/filter-with-dynamic-dict-peewee-orm)

I can apply filter on Model1 attributes by appending filter at the end of join, like this: `Model1.select(Model1, Model2).join(Model2).filter(Model1.name == 'foo').dicts()` and that works as expected. I followed the documentation here: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.filter

If I attempt to apply any filter with attributes from Model2 like `filter(Model2.id == 22)`, it fails with an `AttributeError`.

I tried to create a CTE and applied filter on it but didn't work throwing an AttributeError.

is it possible to achieve what I am attempting? Please can you guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.where()` and not `.filter()`:

```
query = (Model1
         .select(...)
         .join(Model2)
         .where((Model1.field == 1) & (Model2.other == 2)))
```

The docs provide many examples, please consult them. http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#filtering-records